# Can GTK's main loop run with from a secondary thread?

Tags: gtk

Is it possible to run GTK's main loop in a secondary thread instead of in the main thread?

Comment: Despite the imperfect English, this *is* a real question. The OP is a beginner on SO and should be forgiven the lack of eloquence. The answer is yes, you can run GTK's main loop in a thread other than the main thread. GTK doesn't care which thread the main loop is running in, **as long as all entries to the GTK API come from the same thread**, the one that is running the main loop.

Comment: @user4815162342, if you understand the question please [edit] it... commenting when voting to re-open is useful but you help everyone, now and in the future if you make it understandable to more people.

Comment: The question makes perfect sense to a GTK programmer...Any edits made would be to correct the minor grammatical errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the main loop in any thread, but you should only access it from the thread that it was created in.

However, it isn't a common thing to do, and there may be a better way of doing whatever it is that you're trying to do.